# HTTPS reverse proxy for HTTP-only web service

Tags: https, reverse-proxy

I have a Windows web service application running on HTTP, no HTTPS support. Can someone recommend some lightweight HTTPS reverse proxy in front of it, so connections to it from the outside can go through HTTPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most light-weight tools to SSL enable a http, or other, service is [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/).

Comment: Totally worthy. It's a good fit.